# How to select increasing values from two vectors - 'weaving two vectors'

Tags: r, sorting, time

I have two vectors of different length. Both vectors have values in order:

```
v1 <- c(1:5, 11:18)
v2 <- c(2, 7, 8, 14)
v1         
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
v2
# [1]  2  7  8 14
```

Starting with the first element of v1, I want to *alternate* between two vectors and select one element from each of the vectors at a time. Each subsequent value to be selected should be *larger* than the preceeding value.

The desired sequence after 'weaving' the two vectors:

```
c(1, 2, 3, 7, 11, 14, 15)
```

Thus, we start with the first element in v1 (`1`). Then, the next element should be selected from v2 *and* be larger than the preceeding selected value; we pick `2` from v2 (`2 > 1`). Next value should come from v1 and be larger than `2`: we pick `3` from v1. Then `7` from v2 (`7 > 3`), `11` from v1 (`11 > 7`), and so on, alternating between the vectors, picking increasing values.

When there are no more elements in v2 that is greater than the preceeding value in v1, we terminate the selection of values. Thus, in this case, `15` is the last value we pick from v1 (16, 17, 18 are discarded):

[image]

---

I would prefer vectorized operations instead of unnecessary loops.

Extra: my dummy code is in int. But my actual data is well structured time values that I can directly use as arguments for functions from the 'lubridate' package. Is there any function that can do the job?

Q1) Is there an existing function that does this?
Q2) Is there a way to do this in a vectorized approach instead of looping and trimming the input vector after each loop?

Comment: Q1 - probably not, this seem like a very unusual operation. Q2 - probably not a vectorized way. At least not in a scalable way. Operations where the next iteration depends on the outcome of the previous operation are generally not vectorizable. "Looping and trimming" sound bad though (esp. the trimming part), I would essentially walk two iterators through the vectors in a single `while` loop.

Comment: Well there's `union`, but if you look at the code, it simply does `unique(c(as.vector(x), as.vector(y)))`.

Comment: @Alexis OP wants to skip values frequently, the general algo is 1st element of x, 1st element of y greater than max so far, next element of x greater than max so far, next element of y greater than max so far... Much more complicated than a simple union.

Comment: Ah, true, didn't read closely enough.

Comment: what happens when short vector has be used up, and several higher values remain in long vector?  Answer has all the remaining? Or just 1st one? Or just last one?

Comment: @dww Just the 1st one! Thanks for clearing things up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this is general enough:

```
# extend the shorter of the two vectors, bind them to a matrix, 
m <- cbind(v1, v2[1:length(v1)])

# 'weave' the two vectors and bind with a vector index
m2 <- cbind(c(t(m)), 1:2)

# remove NA and duplicates
m3 <- m2[!is.na(m2[ , 1]) & !duplicated(m2[ , 1]), ]

# order 
m3 <- m3[order(m3[ , 1]), ]

# to pick values from every other vector,
# create a run-length id based on the vector index,
# remove duplicates of it, and use as index 
m3[!duplicated(cumsum(c(1L, m3[ , 2][-nrow(m3)] != m3[ , 2][-1]))), 1]
# [1]  1  2  3  7 11 14 15
```

---

Same idea, but slightly more compact with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
m <- cbind(v1, v2[1:length(v1)])
d <- data.table(v = c(t(m)), g = 1:2)
d2 <- d[!is.na(v) & !duplicated(v), ]
setorder(d2, v)
d2[ , .SD[1], by = rleid(g)]$v
# [1]  1  2  3  7 11 14 15
```

Comment: Hi @Not-SoberCoder! I'm curious to hear if my solution worked the way you wanted. Cheers